# JsonObject null when sending from javascript to action struts2

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

Im working with struts2 .
and when Im Sending A JsonObject from js to action , JsonObject is null.

Code :

Js file :

```
var data = {"data":[{"name":"ABC","age":"20"},{"name":"XYZ","age":"22"}]};

$.ajax({
      url: "Exam1/start",
      data: data, 
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (res) {
       alert("OK");
      }
    });
```

and struts.xml :

```
   <package name="default" extends="json-default" namespace="/">    
    <action name="start" method="init" class="ta.action.InitAction">
         <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
         <param name="ignoreInterfaces">false</param>
         <param name="root">data</param>
        <result type="json"/>   
    </action>
</package>
```

and Action :

```
public class InitAction  extends ActionSupport{
   private List<Student> data; // set and get 
   public String init() {
      System.out.println("Data" + data );// data is null ( Why ??? )
   }
}
```

and Class Student :

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}


}
```

Comment: Do you have a publicly accessible getter/setter for the `data` property?

Comment: I have a publicly accessible getter/settet for data. And using struts2-json-plugin.